# core data object not saved in sqlite

Tags: swift, sqlite, core-data

I'm having a problem that the sqlite file is only edited when adding the objects in the first time.After that only the sqlite-shm file is changed. So when I relaunch the app nothing changes.Here is the core data stack in the AppDelegate

```
lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
    let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("StoriesCoreData", withExtension: "mom")
    let mom = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL!)

    let psc = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: mom!)

    let urls = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
    print (urls[urls.endIndex-1])
    let storeURL = (urls[urls.endIndex-1]).URLByAppendingPathComponent("stories.sqlite")

    var error: NSError? = nil

    var store: NSPersistentStore?
    do {
        store = try psc.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: storeURL, options: nil)
    } catch var error1 as NSError {
        error = error1
        store = nil
    } catch {
        fatalError()
    }
    if (store == nil) {
        print("Failed to load store")
    }

    var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext()
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = psc

    return managedObjectContext
    }()

func saveContext() {
    var error: NSError? = nil
    let moc : NSManagedObjectContext? = self.managedObjectContext
    if moc == nil {
        return
    }
    if !managedObjectContext.hasChanges {
        return
    }
    do {
        try managedObjectContext.save()
        return
    } catch let error1 as NSError {
        error = error1
    }

    print("Error saving context: \(error?.localizedDescription)\n\(error?.userInfo)")
    abort()
}
```

Here is how the objects are initialized:

```
    let aStory = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("PersonalizedStory", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as! PersonalizedStory
    aStory.childrenMode = NSNumber(int: 0)
    aStory.hidden = NSNumber(int: 0)
    aStory.lastEdited = NSDate()
    aStory.parentStoryDownloadDate = NSDate()
    aStory.parentStoryID = "10000"
    aStory.parentWriterID = "guest"
    aStory.personalizedStoryID = "10"
    aStory.pictureList = []
    aStory.userID = "guest"
    aStory.inSection = NSSet()
    saveContext()

    let aSection = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("LibrarySection", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as! LibrarySection
    aSection.personalizedStoriesOrder = []
    aSection.sectionName = "AllStories"
    aSection.userID = "guest"
    aSection.personalizedStoriesOrder!.append(aStory)
    aSection.hasStory = NSSet()
    saveContext()

    aSection.addObject(aStory, forKey: "hasStory")
    aStory.addObject(aSection, forKey: "inSection")


    saveContext()
```

Here is the fetch request and modification:

```
func allStories () -> [PersonalizedStory]? {
    var error : NSError? = nil
    let fetchStories = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "LibrarySection")
    let sectionsForUser = NSPredicate(format: "userID = %@", argumentArray: [userID])
    let all = NSPredicate(format: "sectionName == %@", argumentArray: ["AllStories"])
    let fetchPredicates = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [sectionsForUser,all])
    fetchStories.predicate = fetchPredicates
    var result : [LibrarySection]?
    do {
        result =  try appDelegate.managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchStories) as? [LibrarySection]

    } catch {
        result = nil
    }
    let theSection = result!.first!.personalizedStoriesOrder!

    for story in theSection {
        story.setValue(1, forKey: "childrenMode")
    }
    appDelegate.saveContext()
    return theSection

}
```

So in when I print out the stories later on childMode is set to 1.

However when I relaunch every thing is set back to 0.

And when I check the app folder

[image: only -shm -wal files are changed]

Comment: SQLite usually puts new data into its journal files, which is fine, because it also reads those files. The fact that it's using a journal file is not relevant to the problem you're having.

Comment: Show the save code, does it return an error? Is the attribute transient for some reason?